# select non unique combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I've below data

```
dep, arr
uk, usa
usa, uk
china,aus
aus,china
brazil,uk
```

how can I get the unique and non unique combination from above data

unique combination `(departure to arrival and arrival to departure both are present)`

```
dep, arr
uk, usa
usa, uk
china,aus
aus,china
```

non unique combination, where only `departure to arrival or arrival to departure` is present but not vice versa

```
brazil,uk
```

using this sql query, but not sure how to target specific to non unique

```
Select          
           dep, arr,  count(*) over (partition by least(dep, arr), greatest(dep, arr) order by dep) rnk
From flights
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you explain the expected results?

Comment: Why is `brazil,uk` non-unique?

Answer (score 2):

How about simple subquery?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from flights;

DEP    ARR
------ -----
uk     usa
usa    uk
china  aus
aus    china
brazil uk
```

This is what you call "unique combination":

```
SQL> select dep, arr
  2  from flights
  3  where dep||'~'||arr in (select arr||'~'||dep from flights);

DEP    ARR
------ -----
usa    uk
uk     usa
aus    china
china  aus
```

And this is what you call "non-unique combination":

```
SQL> select dep, arr
  2  from flights
  3  where dep||'~'||arr not in (select arr||'~'||dep from flights);

DEP    ARR
------ -----
brazil uk

SQL>
```

---

Delimiter is set to `~` character, presuming that it isn't contained in `dep` nor `arr` column values. If it is, then substitute it with something that doesn't exist (could be *any* other character).

Comment: In a generic case, this solution may give false-positive matches when you have the `dep`, `arr` values `'a-b'`, `'c'` and `'b-c'`, `'a'`.

Comment: Oh, @MTO, I'm confident that you'll manage to find delimiter which isn't used in values stored in these columns.

Comment: @Littlefoot, how dep||'-'||arr able to find both combination in inner query ?

Comment: @morgan You can use a case expression in the outer query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists()` to ensure that departure is not available available as arrival and arrival is not available as departure:

Query

```
select dep,arr from tab1 a
  where not exists
(
 select 1 from tab1 b where a.dep=b.arr and a.arr=b.dep
)
```

Output:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| brazil | uk |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cya4VlUf)

Answer (score 1):

You may use simple aggregation with `greatest/least` as group by expressions to count appearances of 2-element tuple including permutations.

```
with sample(dep, arr) as (
  select 'uk', 'usa' from dual union all
  select 'usa', 'uk' from dual union all
  select 'china', 'aus' from dual union all
  select 'aus', 'china' from dual union all
  select 'brazil', 'uk' from dual
)
select
  greatest(dep, arr) as loc1,
  least(dep, arr) as loc2,
  case count(*)
    when 2
    then 'two way'
    else 'one way'
  end as type_
from sample
group by
  greatest(dep, arr),
  least(dep, arr)
```

Which for your sample data returns

| LOC1 | LOC2 | TYPE_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usa | uk | two way |
| china | aus | two way |
| uk | brazil | one way |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8d5LafcB)

Place `count(*) = N` in the `having` clause to return only required category of combination.

Answer (score 0):

a single Join would do it

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
    ("dep" varchar2(6), "arr" varchar2(5))
;
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO tab1 ("dep", "arr")
         VALUES ('uk', 'usa')
    INTO tab1 ("dep", "arr")
         VALUES ('usa', 'uk')
    INTO tab1 ("dep", "arr")
         VALUES ('china', 'aus')
    INTO tab1 ("dep", "arr")
         VALUES ('aus', 'china')
    INTO tab1 ("dep", "arr")
         VALUES ('brazil', 'uk')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
SELECT t1."dep", t1."arr" FROM tab1 t1 JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1."dep" =  t2."arr"  and t2."dep" = t1."arr"
```

| dep | arr |
| --- | --- |
| usa | uk |
| uk | usa |
| aus | china |
| china | aus |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VZT5wUJ1)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you want to remove the `ORDER BY` clause in the analytic function (so you count over the entire window) and then filter in an outer query:

```sql
SELECT dep, arr
FROM   (
  SELECT dep,
         arr,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(dep, arr), GREATEST(dep, arr)) AS cnt
  FROM   flights
)
WHERE  cnt = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE flights(dep, arr) AS
SELECT 'uk',     'usa'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'usa',    'uk'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'china',  'aus'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aus',    'china' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'brazil', 'uk'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| brazil | uk |

If you can have multiple flights in each direction then count the number of `DISTINCT` departures or arrivals in each combination:

```sql
SELECT dep, arr
FROM   (
  SELECT dep,
         arr,
         COUNT(DISTINCT dep) OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(dep, arr), GREATEST(dep, arr))
           AS cnt
  FROM   flights
)
WHERE  cnt = 1;
```

Outputs:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| brazil | uk |

and:

```sql
SELECT dep, arr
FROM   (
  SELECT dep,
         arr,
         COUNT(DISTINCT dep) OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(dep, arr), GREATEST(dep, arr))
           AS cnt
  FROM   flights
)
WHERE  cnt = 2;
```

Outputs:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| aus | china |
| china | aus |
| uk | usa |
| usa | uk |

And, if you want to display all the rows and the direction:

```sql
SELECT dep,
       arr,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT dep)
              OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(dep, arr), GREATEST(dep, arr))
       WHEN 1
       THEN 'one-way'
       ELSE 'two-way'
       END AS direction
FROM   flights;
```

Outputs:

| DEP | ARR | DIRECTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aus | china | two-way |
| china | aus | two-way |
| brazil | uk | one-way |
| uk | usa | two-way |
| usa | uk | two-way |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yMaZVpY4)

Answer (score 0):

[@Littlefoot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76142617/1509264) may generate false positives and false negatives; for example if you have `arr`, `dep` of `a-b`, `c` and `b-c`, `a` then the string concatenation will give `a-b-c` when matched in one direction. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p1fihvR5)

You can perform a similar test using `IN` with multiple terms and it does not suffer from false-positives as it does not use string concatenation to combine the terms.

To get the two-way flights:

```sql
SELECT dep, arr
FROM   flights
WHERE  (dep, arr) IN ( SELECT arr, dep FROM flights );
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| usa | uk |
| uk | usa |
| aus | china |
| china | aus |

To get the one-way flights:

```sql
SELECT dep, arr
FROM   flights
WHERE  (dep, arr) NOT IN ( SELECT arr, dep FROM flights );
```

Which outputs:

| DEP | ARR |
| --- | --- |
| brazil | uk |

If you want to get all the flights and label them then use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT dep,
       arr,
       CASE
       WHEN (dep, arr) IN ( SELECT arr, dep FROM flights )
       THEN 'two-way'
       ELSE 'one-way'
       END as direction
FROM   flights;
```

Which outputs:

| DEP | ARR | DIRECTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uk | usa | two-way |
| usa | uk | two-way |
| china | aus | two-way |
| aus | china | two-way |
| brazil | uk | one-way |

---

However, this method requires you to query the table twice, once for the main query and once for the `IN` filter so it is less efficient than using [the `COUNT` analytic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76142949/1509264) (even if that query seems slightly more complicated).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_DafcqxX)